# php loop through multidimensional to check for id

Tags: php, api

I have pulled this array from facebook using the api,

These are a list of checkins.

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [place] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 131703340219561
                            [name] => Marrakech
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [city] => Marrakesh
                                    [country] => Morocco
                                    [latitude] => 31.623668132472
                                    [longitude] => -7.98555101201
                                    [zip] => 40000
                                )

                        )

                    [id] => 10151818357364165
                    [created_time] => 2013-08-26T18:05:47+0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [place] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 143805719105986
                            [name] => WESTIVAL Music Festival -31st Jan - 3rd Feb 2013
                            [location] => Westow House
                            [start_time] => 2013-01-31T18:00:00+0000
                        )

                    [id] => 10151702856746562
                    [created_time] => 2013-02-03T00:50:39+0000
                )
```

I want to search through array and check whether an ['place'] id is present.

How would i do this?

Comment: Well: How do you iterate over an array? PHP 101

Comment: thanks kingkero - think im still at php 100.1. Any tips? tried for each but couldnt get deeper into the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hasPlaceId($result, $targetId)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('data', $result)
        return false;
    foreach($result['data'] as $value)
    {
        if(array_key_exists('place', $value) && array_key_exists('id', $value['place']) && $value['place']['id'] == $targetId)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you lots and lots prizma - save me hours of trail and error :)

Answer (score 0):

use foreach loop and check the id if it matches place you are there.

for example:

```
foreach($aArray['data'] as $iK=> $aData){
  if($iK == 'place'){
    //do something
  }  
  foreach($aData[$iK] as $iV =>$aData2){
    //do something
  }
}
```